# Java jdbc, спустя некоторое время пропадает соединение с БД

Tags: java, jdbc

Программа в фоновом режиме обращается к БД. 
Спустя некоторое время работы (несколько часов, может сутки, может быть после перехода компьютера в спящий режим и обратно), пропадает соединение с БД.

Получаем исключение: **java.lang.Exception: Не удалось установить соединение TCP/IP к серверу 192.168.1.100 по порту 1433. Ошибка: "connect timed out. Проверьте свойства соединения. Убедитесь, что на сервере запущен экземпляр SQL Server и он принимает TCP/IP-соединения по порту. Убедитесь, что TCP-соединения по этому порту не блокируются брандмауэром".**

Перезапуск программы помогает.

Какая может быть причина и как правильно обработать исключение? Ведь после каждого запроса коннект закрывается и открывается новый для следующего. И это не помогает.

Код программы в упрощенном виде:

```
while (true) {
  sleep(100);
  String mainSql = "SELECT 1"
  try {
     ResultSet rs = ConnectToDB.ExecQueryRS(mainSql);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
  } finally {
     ConnectToDB.closeConnection();
  }
```

Класс ConnnectToDB

```
public class ConnectToDB {
public static Connection conn = null;
private static String user = "";
private static String pass = "";
private static String server = "";
private static String databaseName = "";
private static String port = "";


public ConnectToDB() {
}

public static String getConnectionUrl() {
    return "jdbc:sqlserver://" + getServer() + ":" + getPort() +
            "; databaseName=" + getDatabaseName()  + ";" + "username=" +
            getUser() + ";password=" + getPass();
}

public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(getConnectionUrl());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        conn = null;
        LogInFile.log("ERROR", "ConnectToDB|getConnection", "Ошибка подключения к БД: "+e);
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
}

public static ResultSet ExecQueryRS(String q) {
    ResultSet r = null;
    try {
        Statement stmt = getConnection().createStatement();
        r = stmt.executeQuery(q);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        r = null;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        r = null;
    }
    return r;
}

public static void closeConnection() {
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
            conn = null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LogInFile.log("ERROR", "ConnectToDB|closeConnection", "Ошибка закрытия соединения с БД: "+ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все правильно. СУБД, может самостоятельно сбрасывать коннект с БД в случае если соединение долго не используется. Коннект с БД это ценный (и ограниченный) ресурс и СУБД самостоятельно распоряжается этим хозяйством.

Вижу 3 способа "борьбы" с этим явлением:

1) Перед запросом проверять жив ли коннект?

2) Если позволяет JDBC драйвер, то устанавливать флаг `autoreconnect=true` - JDBC драйвер MySQL позволяет это делать, SQL Server - не уверен, что позволяет - почитайте описание драйвера

3) Использовать пулинг JDBC коннекта. Например [Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/). Пулинг хорош тем, что позволяет абстрагироваться от самого коннекта и возложить задачу конкретного конннекта к менеджеру пула JDBC коннектов - на уровне кода вам надо импортировать либу, написать небольшой конфиг файл (гугль в помощь - примеров в сети много)

Наиболее профессиональный способ - это конечно же вариант №3